# Satis - password protection

Tags: satis

I have a satis repository which connects the dots for my private bitbucket repositories. I want to be able to charge for access to this satis repository by sending over the applications (my base application uses Laravel) secret key and validate it against the users account. Is there a way to send over the key for me to validate?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satis is simply a script that compiles some files that can be hosted anywhere where static file hosting is available.

If you want to add access control, it is not a question of using Satis correctly, but implementing access control for static HTTP resources.

By the way: The only authentication protocol Composer offers is HTTP Authentication (aka ".htpasswd"), so if you want a sophisticated payment and access control, you have to implement something that would send 401 HTTP status codes, wait for a username/password and check if that account paid.

Comment: May you please elaborate on that sophisticated payment and access control process that you are describing please ?

Comment: I had nothing concrete in mind. I'd suppose that by using credentials you'd be able to identify who is requesting something, then check with the database hosting what that account has paid for, and either grant access or deny it.